# How to batch retrieve elements with button in tag name in selenium in python

Tags: ios, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I would like to use Selenium in python to get all elements that have "button" in the tag name. For example, "icon-button" is an appropriate tag name. I have tried using contains in the code below, but I cannot get the elements. Please let me know if you know where I can fix this.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//form/@*[contains(name(), 'button')]")
print(len(buttons))
```

All my attempts have resulted in a length of zero.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//*[contains(name(),'button')]")
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(name(), 'button')]")
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tag[contains(@tag='button')]")
```

Sample HTML

```
<icon-button data-location="item_details:item_info:comment_icon_button" location-2="comment_icon_button" variant="with-text" label="コメント" defined="" data-js-focus-visible="">
    <icon-comment-square-outline color="primary" defined=""></icon-comment-square-outline>
</icon-button>
```

latest code 6:45 24th Aplil (with output results)

```
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
print(location(), len(buttons)) //output is 6
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(name(), 'button')]")
print(location(), len(buttons)) //output is 0
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[label='コメント']")
print(location(), len(buttons)) //output is 0
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[text='コメント']")
print(location(), len(buttons)) //output is 0
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What are all the different *-icon tags you are looking for? Can you post a link to the page? There may be a different way to do this.

Comment: Since it is difficult to attach a link, I have added the relevant HTML to the body of the text. The purpose is to make sure that the element continues to be retrieved even if the HTML is updated. The tag name of the element I want to retrieve contains "button" and there is a ”コメント” in the attribute, so I intend to retrieve all elements with "button" in the tag name and then check the "コメント" in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to grab all elements and then look for `label="コメント"`, you can just create a locator that looks specifically for the `label="コメント"` attribute.

A CSS selector can do this

```
[label='コメント']
```

Your code would look like

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[label='コメント']")
```

If you want to change the expected label, you can use a variable

```
label = "コメント"
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"[label='{label}']")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The below is latest code. The output result is 6, 0, 0, 0.
In other words, the code using the label='comment' you mentioned is not getting the element

driver.get(url)
sleep(10)
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
print(location(), len(buttons))
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(name(), 'button')]")
print(location(), len(buttons))
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[label='コメント']")
print(location(), len(buttons))
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[text='コメント']")
print(location(), len(buttons))

Comment: Given the code you just posted, each time you are printing `buttons` (plural) but my code stores the value in `button` (singular). If my code didn't work, you would have received an element not found exception on that line. Do a `button.click()` or `print(button.text)` (if it actually contains some text) or something similar to test it.

Comment: I am sorry but I mistook the button to buttons in your code. After I changed buttons the code you mention, it is make sence.
The LABEL is variable and may be a comment or a number. Numbers are usually less than 10 (1-10), but rarely more than 10. In this case, how should I describe it? ([label='コメント'] or [label='1'], or [label='2']...[label='10']

Comment: I updated my answer with one approach to changing the label expected text

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `find_elements_by_tag_name` method of the Selenium WebDriver object to retrieve a list of elements with a particular tag name. To retrieve elements with a tag name based on a button click, you can do the following:

1. First, import the required modules:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

2. Instantiate a WebDriver object:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

3. Navigate to the desired webpage:

```
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

4. Define a function that retrieves the desired elements:

```
def get_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name):
    return driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name)
```

1. Define an event handler function that calls the
2. `get_elements_by_tag_name` function with the desired tag name:

```
def button_click_handler(tag_name):
    elements = get_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name)
    for element in elements:
        print(element.text)
```

6. Attach the event handler function to a button element:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='my-button']"))
)
button.click()
button_click_handler('div')  # Replace 'div' with the desired tag name
```

In this example, the `button_click_handler` function is called when the button with the my-button ID is clicked. The `get_elements_by_tag_name` function is called with the desired tag name, and the retrieved elements are printed to the console.

Note that the above code is just an example, and you will need to modify it to suit your specific needs.

Comment: `.find_elements_by_tag_name()` was deprecated long ago, replaced by `.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "locator")`. BUT, you still haven't answered the question.